# How to use JavaScript to make an option selected in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

The code below is for a dropdown in html:

```
<html>
<body>

    <select id="demo1" name="demo2" type="text">
      <option value="london">London</option>
      <option value="paris">Paris</option>
      <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

How to make the option with value "paris" selected?
Please consider it is not possible to change anything in the code above.

The code was edited to give more details because unfortunately the answers did not work on this question.

The below code did not work as well:

```
<script>
        var selectedtext = "paris";
        document.getElementById("demo1").selected = selectedtext;
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('option[value=paris]').selected = true;`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad it is not name ;)

Comment: There is no reason that either of the approaches I've shown in my answer below wouldn't work, as I've shown it working in my answer. However, your `select` has `type=text`, which is invalid since a `select` can't have a `type` attribute. If it's not working, there is a different issue.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Have you made sure to add the `script` ***after*** the HTML has been parsed by placing it just before the closing `body` tag?

Comment: Also, the code you've shown that you tried that didn't work is not code that anyone here has suggest you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what position the `option` you want selected will always be in, you can use either of the following approaches:

1. To modify the DOM object property of the `option`, set the [`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property (which starts counting from 0) on the element.

```js
document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = 1;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <!-- A select element can't have a type attribute -->
    <select id="demo1" name="demo2" type="text">
      <option value="london">London</option>
      <option value="paris">Paris</option>
      <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

2. If you do want to alter the HTML state of the element, you can use the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method on the element:

```js
document.querySelector("select").options[1].setAttribute("selected", "selected");

// Just for demo purposes:
console.log(document.querySelector("select").outerHTML);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <!-- A select element can't have a type attribute -->
    <select id="demo1" name="demo2" type="text">
      <option value="london">London</option>
      <option value="paris">Paris</option>
      <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

But, if you only know the text of the `option` that should be selected and not its position, then you can use the following CSS selector with `.querySelector` to isolate the right `option` and select it:

```js
let input = "paris";

// Either one of these will work:

// To affect the HTML state:
document.querySelector("option[value='" + input + "']").setAttribute("selected", "selected");

// To affect the DOM Object property:
document.querySelector("option[value='" + input + "']").selected = true;

// Just for demo purposes:
console.log(document.querySelector("select").outerHTML);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <!-- A select element can't have a type attribute -->
    <select id="demo1" name="demo2" type="text">
      <option value="london">London</option>
      <option value="paris">Paris</option>
      <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably because it's brittle. I didn't down vote however

Comment: @AluanHaddad The requirement is brittle, not the solution.

Comment: Fair enough, sir

Comment: Where did you get (1) from? The code in the question is a simplify version of the main code. So the answer also can be simple too.

Comment: @dxb The 1 represents the index of the `option` that should become selected. In your example "Paris" is the second `option`. Indexes start counting from 0, so the second one would be 1. You did not indicate in your question that what you are showing is a simplified version of the code. Are you saying that it may not always be the second `option`, but it will always be the `option` with `Paris` as the text?

Comment: It was only an example, and not always the same number for the choice to put 1 or 2 for the index. The point is to make the option selected based on the text from other input that can be different each time. This is why I used a variable for the text.

Comment: @dxb Ok (that really should have been stated in the question), but I have updated my answer. What you're looking for is at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways:

if the options might change order you select the value itself

```js
document.querySelector('[value=paris]').selected = true
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise you can use `selectIndex`:

```js
document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex = 1
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

this way....

```js
document.querySelector('select').value = 'paris';
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>
```

Or, with full use in a form:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']


myForm.city.value = 'paris'
```

```html
<form  name="my-form">

  <select name="city">
    <option value="london">London</option>
    <option value="paris">Paris</option>
    <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Comment: The OP is not even showing a `form` and no `form` is required in order to use a `select` in many cases, so not sure why you show that. Also, accessing a `form` via `document.forms` is considered a legacy approach, whereas a DOM method like `querySelector()` is the modern, standard approach.

Comment: Read the comment?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Another point of view is to think that the PO forgot to show its use of a form, without being aware of the importance of the usefulness of a hierarchy in this case, which avoids having to reference X times each of the multiple elements present in a form. What beginners are too rarely aware of. There are enough of you here to show this straightforward approach. a different point of view is always useful and does not deserve to be sanctioned with a negative vote.

Comment: The OP has stated that the HTML cannot be changed and your answer shows changed HTML. Also, as I said, even if you were to use a `form`, the modern, standard would be to use `.querySelector()` and not legacy approaches. Lastly, accessing the `form` doesn't save you anything when you then have to access different elements within the form, you still have to perform those queries, so whatever benefit you seem to be implying by using a `form` doesn't really exist.

Comment: @ScottMarcus OK, since you have everything answered, I improved my answer.

Comment: But you still have all that incorrect stuff?

Comment: Oh no, no, no! **"Working" code is in no way synonymous with correct or good code.**  And out of date or poorly performant code is not useful to know. In fact, some of the biggest harm done here is by showing old, inefficient code. You are free to post whatever answer you like.... And I am free to vote on the quality of it, just as you are. That's how the site works.